# read excel file with words and write it to csv file in Python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv

I have an excel file with string stored in each cell:

```
rtypl   srtyn   OCVXZ   srtyn
KPLNV   KLNWZ   bdfgh   KLNWZ
xcvwh   mvwhd   WQKXM   mvwhd
GYTR    xvnm    YTZN    YTZN
ngws    jklp    PLNM    jklp
```

I wanted to read excel file and write it in csv file. As you can see below:

```
import pandas as np
import csv

df = pd.read_excel(file, encoding='utf-16')
words= open("words.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(words, dialect='excel')
for item in df:
    wr.writerow(item)
```

But it reads the each line in separated alphabet and not as a string.

```
r,t,y,p,l
```

I am limited to write file as csv as I gonna use the result in a library that has lots of facility for csv file. Any advice on how I can read all the rows as a string in the cell is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the easiest solution:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file, encoding='utf-16')
df.to_csv('words.csv', encoding='utf-16')
```

Comment: it does not work in case if I  have some other languages text in rows.it shows ??? in text

Answer (score 0):

Adding to zipa : If excel has multiple sheets  : you can also try

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Sheet1')
df.to_csv('words.csv')
```

Refer : 
http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/intro-to-pandas-data-structures/